# Command line piping to match first line of output

Tags: cmd

Is there a way to achieve the following through a single command line command using pipes?

1. List the files in descending order of modified date (dir /b /o:-d)
2. Check if the first line of the above output is "checksum.txt"
3. If there is match, output "found" else "not found"

I am trying to avoid creating temporary file by redirecting the output of "dir" command above and then reading the first line in the file to check for a match.

Comment: So does it have to be a single line? You can also loop over the output of a command using `for`. Also, does it have to be done using pipes, or are you just looking for a way to check if `checksum.txt` is the most recent file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not on a single line, but it does work without a temporary file by looping over the results of the `dir` command. This would work inside a batch file:

```
setlocal enableextensions
for /F %%s in ('dir /b /o:-d') do (
  if "%%s"=="mk.bat" echo found & goto :eof 
  echo not found & goto :eof
)
```

With a bit of force you could do that on a single line as well:

```
cmd /e:on /c "@(for /F %s in ('dir /b /o:-d') do @(if "%s"=="mr.bat" echo found & exit /b) & @(echo not found & exit /b ))"
```

Note a couple of differences:

- Using (more) parentheses instead of newlines to group commands,
- Don't use `goto :eof`, because it won't work in this setup,
- Instead, use `exit /b` to exit the script (could be used in the script above as well),
- Wrap the whole thing in double quotes and pass it to cmd, to prevent the current shell to be exited. Use `/e:on`, although you could also start the command with `setlocal enableextensions &`,
- Use `@` to suppress extra output of the sub-commands that are processed.